# Google+ sign-in with Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, google-plus, turbolinks

I'm building a rails application that makes use of the Turbolinks stuff that comes with Rails 4.  I am also trying to use the Google+ sign in button for user authentication.

I have everything working except in one case:
If the user visits more than one page before logging in, the google+ sign in process doesn't work.  Basically, the Turbolinks magic is breaking the Google+ signin button.  (If the user signs in right away, everything works perfectly)

That said, I can see where the problem seems to be.  When the google+ js api loads, it attaches a hidden iframe to the body of the html document.  This gets blown away when turbolinks loads another page.  I bet this iframe is required for completing the Google+ signin process.

Has anyone crossed a similar bridge?  I'm not sure how to prevent turbolinks from removing the iframe.  An alternative may be to get the Google+ Api to re-initialize, but nothing like that is mentioned in the Google Plus docs.

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with the [Facebook login button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button/) and [Bugherd sidebar](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button/).
You will need to reload your components on every page:fetch and page:change events.

Here is the pseudo code I use for facebook login:

```
$(document)
   .on('page:fetch', saveFacebookRoot)
   .on('page:change', restoreFacebookRoot)
```

I think you can do almost the same think with the Google+ iframe.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately, no love.  When I reload the special iFrame it doesn't help.  Additionally, the google api spits out an error to the console: "Unknown RPC service: oauth2relayReady:#####"

Comment: It works! -- After more poking, I was able to get this to work.  I still get the weird error in the console.  Also, once I signin the application attaches yet another iframe to the dom.  This second iframe doesn't happen under normal conditions... I really appreciate the help, but I think I'm going to ditch turbolinks -- the solution is just a bit too fragile.